# Generic parser with gson (key and content dynamic attributes)

Tags: android, json, gson

I would like to have a generic parser using **Gson**.

How can I do it ? (for below json **attributes**)

**JSON:**

```
{  
   "sku":{  
      "id":"121221",
      "sequence":0,
      "ean":"1121212121121",
      "attributes":{  
         "clothes_size":"S",
         "color":"black"
      }
   }
}
```

with

**Class:**

```
public class Attributes {
    public String label;
    public String value;
}
```

Comment: Post the proper json you are getting, there are methods by which you can do that

Comment: Its still not a proper json you can check [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to map the Attributes use a generic Map as attributes:

```
public SKU {
    private String id;
    private Long sequence;
    private String ean
    private Map<String, String> attributes;
}
```

Comment: I can see, but you cannot do this "instantly", because they are totally different objects, there is no easy match between your json and your obect.

Comment: idean should be just ean, doesn't it?

Comment: Lol, yes. Typo. Thanks. :)

Comment: Works!
@SerializedName("attributes")
    private Map<String, String> attributesMap = new HashMap<>(); Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**First Step:** You have to make modal class for that `JSON` and name it as follows:

**SkuMain.java**

```
public class SkuMain{
   Sku sku;

  public Sku getSku{
    return sku;
  }
}
```

**Sku.java**

```
public class Sku {
  String id;
  String sequence;
  String ean;
  Map<String, String> attributes;

  public attributes getAttributes{
    return attributes;
  }
}
```

**Second Step:** Use the Gson to make it parse as follows:

```
SkuMain objSkuMain = new Gson(). fromJson(yourJsonString, SkuMain.class);
Sku objSku = objSkuMain.getSku();
String dynamicAttributes = new Gson.toJson(objSku.getAttributes());
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String> >() {}.getType(); // define generic type
Map<Integer, Result> mapAttributes= gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(dynamicAttributes), mapType);
```

for `Sku` class you have to make getter setter methods which will get you attributes field also.

Comment: This won't work because the OP is going to have dynamic attributes, not just "clothes_size" and "color".

Comment: He havent mentioned that he is having dynamic attributes

Comment: That's right, it something that I've understood from his "requirements".